# How to make a responsive web layout with a full width header and fixed width body

Tags: html, css

I have an issue that I have seen come up in a couple different sites and I have never been able to find a solution. I have noticed that many other people have had similar issues but every fix that I have seen is not working on the site I am currently working on. Basically what I am trying to do is have a responsive layout with a header that has a repeating background that spans the entire window and a body that has a fixed width. The basic html looks like this:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="header">Header content</div>
    <div id="main-content">Main content here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the css is something like this:

```
html, body{
      width:100%;
}
#header{
      width:100%;
}
#main-content{
      width:1000px;
}
```

This code is not meant to be representative of what is actually on the site that I am working on but to give you an idea of what we are trying to do. To see the actual html, css, etc. please go to http://236887.site-show.com/ and take a look at it. The site initially will look fine but if you shrink the size of the window down so that there is a horizontal scroll bar and then scroll to the right and look at the header, you will see that the repeating background is not going to the full width.

One thing that I did find is that removing the width:1000px on the main-content did fix this issue. However, we need that main-content area to be set to that width. I have also tried setting overflows to hidden and setting floats on the header but nothing seems to correct the issue.

This is especially an issue with Android/iOS systems which run on tablets, smartphones, etc. Any help that you can give me on this issue would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your *main-content* div is set at *1000px* (with *30px* horizontal padding) while your CSS file specifies your header to be *960px*. Increasing the width of your header to match your content will correct the problem.

Here's the code for the fix:

```
.grid-50-50 {
  display: table;
  width: 1030px;
}
```

Comment: @Derekc This is a slightly more complicated problem. The same issue as in this question can be fixed, but there are other issues along with this. To solve this particular problem, you can see that the *#content* div has a width of *1114px*, while your body's *min-width* is only set to *960px.* Change that to *1114px* and you're good to go. However, you'll see that your footer still doesn't look ideal. There are probably other structural issues with your HTML and CSS that are causing this.

Comment: Yeah, I saw Riskbreaker's suggestion to fix the original site and so I set the min-width on the body to 1120px and that seemed to fix the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing it in HTML5 I recommend using 100% `<header>` tag then adding a 100% div 'wrapper'....with this you can have more flexibility.

But for this...If you dont' want to edit the header then set your min to 1030px in your **body tag**:

`body {min-width: 1030px;}`

:)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I would prefer to use the <header> tag as well but there are other reasons as to why we are not using those. I ended up using jmeas's answer for this site but I did use yours for another site that was having a similar issue with the footer. Thanks for the insight.